# How to create auto refresh from static html website

Tags: html, refresh

I have following problem with my website. I created very simple website for my family (including my grandfather) but they don't know much about internet. That is why I have to create auto refresh when they open a website.

My website is here: http://kartingsiemianowice.pl/ (please don't look at the code, because it was created just for few days).

Can you let me know how can I create refresh when they open a website? Because when I will change something and send these files to FTP then they have to refresh page.

Comment: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: You can use `setInterval` a Javascript method to do it

Comment: I'm a beginner and I still don't understand. Can someone send me a working code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Minh Quy stated in the comments, you can use the JS function `setInterval` or `setTimeout`

Example below :

`setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")}, 3000)`;

```
setTimeout(function () {
    location.reload();
}, 3000);
```

The first simple example displays a pop-up alert window every 3 seconds and the second reloads the page after 3 seconds.

So for your purposes, you will need to use this function in conjunction with your existing code to refresh the page when the user visits a specific page or performs a specific action.

Answer (score 4):

Best HTML code placed in head section of the website works good in all browsers.

```
<head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"> </head>
```

Where meta will say to browser what to do and content is time in seconds.

If you need to transfer your visitor to another domain just use:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=https://mlmos.com/">
```

where meta will say what to do, content time in seconds, now 2 or as you wish, then order to redirect to any url, in this case mlmos.com

Hope so this simple solution will help!

Answer (score 3):

Use following code

```
setTimeout(function () {
    location.reload();
}, 1000);
```

where 1000 is the number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code.

Comment: if you are wondering why not to use setInterval instead of setTimeout, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval